# Spring @IfProfileValue should ignore test class, but it is not

Tags: spring, maven-surefire-plugin

So, I am trying to separate tests to run on my CI pipeline using `@IfProfileValue`.

I just put this annotation on one of my test classes and I am **not** defining the value yet. I just want to check that when I run `mvn test`, surefire will ignore this one test.

For some reason, the test gets picked up and executed.

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "test-profile", value = "something")
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTest {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make tests use Spring context you need to run them with `SpringRunner`. In your example you use `Parameterized` runner, which makes test ignore Spring context and as a result `IfProfileValue` annotation is being ignored.